# Using multithreading in loops

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a program, that retrieves data from a website i.e. 1st it gets the categories and subcategories and stores it in the categories table.
Then hits the corresponding category URL and retrieve the products.

I have an outer loop that traverse through category URLs
and an inner loop to handle the pagination 
and one more inner loop to retrieve the products.

Here is my code

```
For item As Integer = 0 To tempTable.Rows.Count - 1
'main loop

     For cycleCount As Integer = -1 To pageNodes.Count - 1
      'pagination loop

       For Each product As HtmlNode In products
         'retrive products here 
       Next


     Next

Next
```

Normally, my code is working fine. But I want to apply multithreading. Therefore I used TPL (Task Parallel Library), on the main loop.

i.e.

```
Parallel.For(0, tempTable.Rows.Count - 1, Sub(item)
'main loop

     For cycleCount As Integer = -1 To pageNodes.Count - 1
      'pagination loop

       For Each product As HtmlNode In products
         'retrive products here 
       Next


     Next

End Sub)
```

Only 2 to 4 record is being is inserted but with duplicate items and after that code crashes This error came: 'One or more errors occured'

So, How do I implement multithreading in my code ?

Comment: You need to post more code. The code you have posted doesn't show the relationships between each looping level and it doesn't get any indication of where the expensive operation is that multi-threading will give a performance boost on.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Parallel.For` wrongly. If you read the expected arguments for your configuration (write `Parallel.For(` and wait for the popup), you would see that the second argument is `toExclusive`. Thus, to emulate `For item As Integer = 0 To tempTable.Rows.Count - 1` you have to write `Parallel.For(0, tempTable.Rows.Count, Sub(item)`. If you change that, your code should work fine.

-- UPDATE

Code sample with easy-to-be-tracked arrays showing that the proposed conversion allows your code to work fine.

```
Dim resultString As String = ""
Dim products(2) As Integer
products(0) = 1
products(1) = 2
For item As Integer = 0 To 1
    'main loop
    For cycleCount As Integer = 0 To 1
        'pagination loop

        For Each product As Integer In products
            'retrive products here
            resultString = resultString & "-" & product.ToString()
        Next
    Next
Next

Dim resultString2 As String = ""
Parallel.For(0, 2, Sub(item)
                       'main loop

                       For cycleCount As Integer = 0 To 1
                           'pagination loop

                           For Each product As Integer In products
                               'retrive products here 
                               resultString2 = resultString2 & "-" & product.ToString()
                           Next

                       Next

                   End Sub)
```

You can compare both `resultString` and `resultString2` and confirm that both variables output exactly the same value, thus the loop is rightly converted.

Comment: It still crashes.
I have searched through, and I have found that when the same piece of code is executing in parallel have the same variable name thus resulting in the duplication of the records.

Comment: Therefore, I need a way to synchronise my code. I tried to use SyncLock but it took same time to execute like the code without threading :-)

Comment: @user1844205 I am executing this piece of code by replacing your arrays and it works perfectly. I will update my answer with a simple code for you to test such that you will understand better where the problem might be (in any case, it is in the data, not in the loop).

Comment: @user1844205 I have updated my answer. Please, confirm that the conversion from normal loop to parallel loop is done fine and start looking for your problem somewhere else (dimensions/values in the arrays).

Comment: Can you please run your code for a big range and try declaring more variables and play with them in the most inner loop ? 
Because I have approx 7-8 variables in my inner most loop and my loop runs around 300 times.

Comment: @user1844205 please try to understand the problem. The only difference between the basic loop and the parallel loop is the external part (For item As Integer = 0 To 1) all what is inside is unimportant. Your original code was clearly wrong (as I hope that you have understood already) because of not accounting for the Parallel.Loop peculiarities. With the correction proposed now you are using the Parallel.Loop rightly. Parallel.Loop tends to work fine, if you see any problem with higher sizes you should test it properly and make sure that is not your fault. (out of space)

Comment: @user1844205 in case of effectively finding the Parallel.Loop (rightly used) works wrongly with big sized-arrays, you should post a different question on this issue (including the exact case you tested with properly declared variables and values assigned to them); and I might not even reply to this one because I don't have experience on this matter. I do know how to use Parallel.Loop properly and I knew that you were using it wrongly (that's why I replied). Does what I say make any sense to you?

Comment: @user1844205 just to make the point clearly: I don't mean that Parallel.Loop cannot work fine; I am reasonably sure (99.99%) that it works without any problem, when used rightly (as proposed). And thus the problem proposed in this question has been solved. You can test it by putting your normal loop and right after it the parallel loop (properly adapted) with the same variables; if the normal one works the parallel one will also work. Otherwise, post the EXACT SITUATION where this does not happen (it would mean a serious bug and thus lots of attention for your new question :)).

Comment: I have tested my normal loops two times, the records are properly inserted and no duplication is found. 
The duplication starts when I run the parallel.For loop :-(

Comment: @user1844205 please make the helping process/problem finding easier: post the exact situation, what means the inputs to your variables. Do some work, if required, to make my help (or any other's one) easier: if the inputs are too many, put then into a text file (and upload the text file here) and write a small bit reading from the text file and populating the variables. In summary: let me (or any other one else) to test your exact conditions without having to spend time on it.

Comment: @user1844205 you should be able to find the issue by your own. What means that I shouldn't be doing that: you have posted a problem and I have given the solution. You have further problems which you are not able to fix and make me keep providing  help (which, ideally, shouldn't be provided as far as you are supposed to be a programmer and what you claim derives, most likely, from a more or less evident bug). I hope that you will understand this point exactly: otherwise I would stop feeling like helping with this kind of "problems" (pretty tired from providing "this kind of help" yesterday).

Comment: @user1844205 I have taken a look at your profile now and you rarely don't award the question! hhmmm. Pitty not having checked that before (I usually do that); apparently you don't belong to group of persons appraising other's effort (and even though you feel that you have right to keep asking?! Certainly curious)